# Is there a way to add keyboard shortcuts to preference panes?

Tags: keyboard

I wanted to add a keyboard shortcut to teleport via the System Preferences.

teleport is a preference pane not an application so I can't select it.

I tried to assign my keyboard to "All applications" but it didn't work.

Edit:
I am more looking for assigning a keyboard shortcut to a Preference pane menu item than assigning a global shortcut to a preference pane.

For example, in teleport I want to assign a shortcut to the menu item "Deactivate teleport". One can access to this menu item by clicking on the teleport icon in the OS X menu bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [create an Automator based service](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut--mac-31463) that opens the specific preference pane.

You can find the preference pane bundles in the `Library/PreferencePanes` set of folders:

- /System/Library/PreferencePanes
- /Library/PreferencePanes
- ~/Library/PreferencePanes

Preference panes are special bundles that when opened from the Finder, will launch **System Preferences.app** and automatically switch to their settings.

1. Create an Automator Service
2. Drag the desired preference pane onto the Automator workflow
3. Add the **Open Finder Items** action…
4. …and select **System Preferences.app** in the action
5. Add a **Watch Me Do** action to record any clicks and interactions with the panel

To assign this workflow as a keyboard shortcut, see this Tuts+ tutorial, [How to Launch Any App with a Keyboard Shortcut](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-launch-any-app-with-a-keyboard-shortcut--mac-31463).

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences panes are applications.

You can find them in :

- `/System/Library/PreferencePanes` (Apple's Prefpanes)
- `/Library/Preferences` (System Wide preferences)
- `~/Library/PreferencePanes` (User only preferences)